# Dados do BD via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho um banco de cliente com ID, NOME, CPF e ENDERECO.
Preciso buscar esses dados via AJAX separadamente.
Mas não estou sabendo como separar os dados de resposta, o script está mandando todos como um unico elemento.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: "listar.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "campo1=dado1 & campo2=dado2 & campo3=dado3 & campo4=dado4",
    dataType: "html"

    }).done(function(resposta) {

        console.log(resposta);

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);

    }).always(function() {
        console.log("completou");
    });
    </script>
```

**AJAx**

```
<?php
include "conexao.inc";
  $result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM tb_pessoas LIMIT 0,1";
  $resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuarios);

 while($registro = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado_usuarios)){
    $id=$registro[0];
    $placa=$registro[1];
    $marca=$registro[2];
    $modelo=$registro[3];

    echo $id;
    echo $nome;
    echo $cpf;
    echo $endereco;
 }
?>
```

BANCO DE DADOS

```
<?php
include "conexao.inc";
  $result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM tb_pessoas LIMIT 0,1";
  $resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuarios);

 while($registro = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado_usuarios)){
    $id=$registro[0];
    $placa=$registro[1];
    $marca=$registro[2];
    $modelo=$registro[3];

    echo $id;
    echo $nome;
    echo $cpf;
    echo $endereco;
 }
?>
```

O problema está na recepção dos dados, não estou sabendo declara-los em outras viariaveis p pd colocar em diferente campos do sistema, de forma individual, cada variavel vinda do BD em um lugar input diferente por exemplo.

Agradeço qq ajuda.

Comment: Vc está retornando os dados como strings "soltas", aí não tem como pegar cada um. Deveria retorna-los como um objeto JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Sam disse, você deve retornar o resultado de uma única vez, ou o javascript não vai conseguir processar o retorno corretamente.

Você pode fazer algo como:

```
<?php
include "conexao.inc";
$result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM tb_pessoas LIMIT 0,1";
$resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuarios);
$usuarios = [];

while($registro = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado_usuarios)){
    $id=$registro[0];
    $placa=$registro[1];
    $marca=$registro[2];
    $modelo=$registro[3];

    $usuarios[] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'nome' => $nome,
        'cpf' => $cpf,
        'endereco' => $endereco 
    ];
 }

 echo json_encode($usuarios);

?>
```

Dessa forma, você estaria montando o retorno dentro do loop e retornaria o JSON esperado pelo Javascript em um formato que ele conseguiria interpretar.